# Image didn't change in jQuery setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to change images based on the user pressing the next button but that isn't happening

```js
var my_image = document.getElementById(main_image);

var image_array = ["https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis2.jpg"];

var image_index = 1;

function change_image(){
 my_image.setAttribute("src", image_array[image_index]);
 image_index++;
 if(image_index > 1){image_index = 0;}
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis.jpg" id ="main_image">

  <button onclick="change_image()"> next </button>
```

Comment: Because your array has just one element and arrays indices begin at zero, not one.

Comment: There also is no variable named `main_image`so the code likely won't find the image. `document.getElementById("main_image");`should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` needs to have a string passed into it. If `main_image` is an element, and not a string, this could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your array index is set wrong

Comment: When answering a question, please be more specific: If the array index is set wrong, then why? what caused this? In this case: "`image_array[1]` does not exist since there is only one element in `image_array`." would be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1- getElementByID expects a string. By not putting quote marks around "main_image" javascript thinks main_image is a variable name, not a value.

2- your array only has one element, so it's position is 0, not 1.

Below your code is working:

```js
var my_image = document.getElementById("main_image");

var image_array = ["https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis2.jpg"];

var image_index = 0;

function change_image(){
 my_image.setAttribute("src", image_array[image_index]);
 image_index++;
 if(image_index > 1){image_index = 0;}
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis.jpg" id ="main_image">

  <button onclick="change_image()"> next </button>
```

Comment: I simplified it because I knew that wasn't the problem. I;m using that small code for something much bigger and I didn't want to overwhelm people with the whole project when it's something small I don't see. I'm just starting javascript so it's lots I don't know. like I didn't know that needed to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can querySelector.
Secondly instead of using onClick in the button use addEventListener.

`
    let my_image = document.querySelector("#main_image");

```
let nextBtn = document.querySelector("button")
let image_array = ["https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis2.jpg"];

let image_index = 0;

const change_image =() => {
my_image.setAttribute("src", image_array[image_index]);
image_index++;
if(image_index > 1){image_index = 0;}
}
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", change_image)
```

`
The answer has been given, I'm only improving on the syntax

Comment: Sorry, I don't wanna use that only because I don't understand it, but your method looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a string into the document.getElementById(). I hope this works for you.